# How to create with Python API a new Perforce user?

Tags: python, perforce

I'm writing a test for a Python script that returns a list of submitters.

The following:

```
    new_user = self.p4.fetch_user('existing-user')
    new_user['User'] = 'new-user'
    self.p4.save_user(new_user)
```

emits:

```
P4Exception: [P4#run] Errors during command execution( "p4 user -i" )

[Error]: "Error in user specification.\nUser name can't be changed from 'existing-user'."
```

What's the Python API call to create a new user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New users are created automatically with:

```
self.p4 = p4python.P4.P4(user='new-user')
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a more explicit code snippet using P4Python:

```
from P4 import P4

p4 = P4()
p4.connect()
newuser = {
    'User': 'newuser',
    'Email': 'newuser@domain.com',
    'FullName': 'New User'
}
p4.save_user(newuser,"-f")
```